# Tkinter метод insert() у виджета Text

Tags: python, tkinter

Если запустить этот код, то нумерация будет показана от большего числа к меньшему. Как сделать наоборот - чтобы сначала показывались меньшие цифры?

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def numerac():
    i=0
    kv=int(kvar_1.get())
    n=0

    for i in range(kv+1):
        if i==0:
            continue
            n+=1
        elif i<10:
            vot_1=("0"+str(i)+"\n")*6
            n+=1
            text_1.insert(0.0,vot_1)
        else:
            vot_2=(str(i)+"\n")*6
            n+=1
            text_1.insert(0.0,vot_2)


kvar=Label(root,text='Введите количество квартир:')
kvar.pack()
kvar_1=Entry(root,bd=2)
kvar_1.pack()

enter=Button(root,text='Вывести список', command=numerac)
enter.pack()

text_1=Text(root,height=20,width=50)
text_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text_1.insert(END, vot_1)
```

И так же для vot_2

Comment: спасибо - все получилось =)

Comment: @user327535 [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).